# Trying to set up haproxy letsencrypt for ssl termination. gateway not answering dns

Tags: domain-name-system, haproxy, lets-encrypt

trying to set up ssl termination with letsencrypt, but some weirdness is happening with dns. I am routing tcp to the existing host to allow the website at adomain.com to manage its own certs until the proxy can --dry-run without errors.

here is my haproxy.conf as is:

```
frontend http-frontend
    bind *:80
    timeout client 1m
    mode http 
    default_backend letsencrypt-backend

frontend https-frontend
    bind *:443
    timeout client 2m
    option tcplog
    mode tcp

    acl is_knight hdr_end(host) -i adomain.com
    acl is_oer  hdr_end(host) -i adifferentdomain.com

    default_backend knight

backend letsencrypt-backend
    mode http
    timeout server 1m
    server letsencrypt 127.0.0.1:8888


backend knight
    timeout server 1m
    mode tcp
    server knightwww 192.168.0.2:443
```

and I'm trying to get ssl certs with

```
sudo certbot certonly --standalone -d adomain.com -d knight.jr1.ca --non-interactive --agree-tos --email email@address.com --http-01-port=8888 --dry-run
```

and the response is

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /directory (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f813819fb00>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',))
```

This had me worried, so I ran a test on [leafDNS](http://leafdns.com)

```
The parent nameservers do not have your nameservers listed
This means the name does not exist or your registrar is experiencing technical difficulties.
```

I just checked the nameservers listed and they contain A-records pointing to the gateway's public IP address

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by something overwriting /etc/resolve.conf..
after some hunting the answer was here:

https://askubuntu.com/a/1001295/946188